# focus a form field on which the function has run (newbie)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to focus a form-field after running a validation-function on a form-field which is triggered "onblur" event of that field.  What I'm trying to do is get the focus back on that field if it is not valid but it doesn't seem to do it.  I've looked for answers on the web but unable to find a solution.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" onblur="validateName();"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateName() {
        var name = document.getElementById("name");
          if (name.value==""||!isNaN(name.value)){
            alert("Please enter a valid name.  You have left the field blank or entered a number.");
            document.getElementById("name").focus();
          }

      };//END validateName
```

`document.getElementById("name").focus();` is not working as expected.

Comment: _"is not working as expected."_ What exactly _is_ happening? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? i just tried it on a code snippet and it works

Comment: You are using redundant event there, onblur clears the focus, should call the validate function on `submit` or `keyup`

Comment: I am expecting the `<input id="name">` to get the `focus()` if that field is blank or is a number; however, the focus is moving to the next field even though `"name"` has not passed validation (i.e. its `""` or `!isNaN`).

Answer (score 2):

The code works for me, but to make it a bit more "clean", I did some changes for you:

HTML:
You can "pass" the element with the function call (`this`), that way, we don't have to look for it anymore in the function itself.

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" onblur="validateName(this)"/>
```

JavaScript:
The element that is blurred, is passed and stored in `element`, we call the "focus()" function directly on that.

```
function validateName(element) {

      if (element.value==""||!isNaN(element.value)){
        alert("Please enter a valid name.  You have left the field blank or entered a number.");
        element.focus();
      }

  };//END validateName
```

Comment: thank you for the cleaner code.  however, my problem with the focus not going back to the `id="name"` field is not solved.  the focus moves to the next field even though the validation is not passed on `id="name"`.